# A late-diverging "approximating solution" for a system of functional equations

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, functional-equations, estimation, parameter-estimation

Peace be upon you,

At the end of this question, I have shown that how computing MLE on an i.i.d Beta distributed data, results in the following system
\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
\psi(\alpha)-\psi(\alpha+\beta) = c_1\\
\psi(\beta)-\psi(\alpha+\beta) = c_2
\end{cases}\\
&c_1 = \frac{1}{n} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n {log(x_i)}\right]
&c_2 = \frac{1}{n} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n {log(1-x_i)} \right]
\end{align*}
where $\psi(.)$ is the digamma function and $x_i\in(0,1]$.

Since I have about 19k of the above system to be solved, then using the iterative methods like Newton-Raphson would take a long time. So, I would like to find a fast-computable late-diverging approximating answer for it. I followed the idea of estimating the $\psi(.)$ function by a, likely, invertible function and substituting it and then solving a new system which results in a closed-form approximating solution.

The simplest candidate for this idea is the Taylor expansion; but it would have a very bad accuracy by getting far from the origin or in other words it diverges quickly.

I suppose that for some functions the divergence would occur very late. For example, $\ln(x)$ is very similar to $ψ(x)$ and it may keep the precision in a large domain. but for such suggestion there is another problem: how to solve the system after substitution.

Maybe, someone will suggest another way for solving the above system. But if some user wants to solve it by the aforementioned technique, he/she can find a much similar basis (than $\{1,x,x^2,...\}$) for a $ψ(x)$ estimation which makes the above system has a closed-form answer.

**Note that I need a "late-diverging" fast-computable answer, either a closed-form approximating answer or any other fast-computable one.**

---

But, how did I reach this system?

We know that the probability density function of the Beta distribution is
\begin{align*}
f(x|\alpha, \beta)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{B(\alpha,\beta)}
\end{align*}
So, the likelihood is
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta)=f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n|\alpha,\beta)=\prod_{i=1}^n{f(x_i|\alpha,\beta)}
\end{align*}
For pre-simplifying the computations, we proceed to find the maximum of the log-likelihood
\begin{align*}
log(\mathcal{L}(\alpha,\beta))=\sum_{i=1}^n{log\left(f(x_i|\alpha,\beta)\right)}
\end{align*}
For maximizing the above log-likelihood, we should solve the following system
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n {(\alpha-1)log(x_i)+(\beta-1)log(1-x_i)-log(B(\alpha,\beta))} \right]=0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n {(\alpha-1)log(x_i)+(\beta-1)log(1-x_i)-log(B(\alpha,\beta))} \right]=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
So, we can write
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n {log(x_i)}\right] =n\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\left[log(B(\alpha,\beta)\right]\\
\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n {log(1-x_i)} \right]=n\frac{\partial}{\partial\beta}\left[log(B(\alpha,\beta)\right]
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Using the formula for partial derivation of Beta function we can write
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n {log(x_i)}\right] =n\left[\psi(\alpha)-\psi(\alpha+\beta)\right]\\
\left[ \sum_{i=1}^n {log(1-x_i)} \right]=n\left[\psi(\beta)-\psi(\alpha+\beta)\right]
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $\psi(.)$ is the digamma function. we can rewrite the above system as
\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
\psi(\alpha)-\psi(\alpha+\beta) = c_1\\
\psi(\beta)-\psi(\alpha+\beta) = c_2
\end{cases}\\
&c_1 = \frac{1}{n} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n {log(x_i)}\right]
&c_2 = \frac{1}{n} \left[ \sum_{i=1}^n {log(1-x_i)} \right]
\end{align*}

Comment: Where does this system of equations arise? What is the application? Are $c_1$ and $c_2$ bounded? Positive? Do you have restrictions on the range of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: It is a replacement of my old answer-comment. I implied some edits to my question so that the origin of variables has become much clear.

Comment: "I need a formula for the values of α and β" There is probably no such thing. Sorry.

Comment: You mean, there is no analytic way to solve the above system? I need the exact results and suppose that it should exist some achievable exact result.

Comment: "I need the exact results" Too bad. "and suppose that it should exist" Should it?

Comment: It is not an imperative sentence it is: I need the exact results and I suppose that (I think that) some achievable exact results exist.
Because the answer doesn't seem to be far from solving a system of integral equations or any other technique.

Comment: @hossayni you dont have closed form expressions all the time. Expectations and what you have in your hands can diverge significantly. But the good thing is that there is always numerical solutions for all practical purposes. The best idea would be to solve the equations numerically assuming $c_i$ as a constant. Then one can see if they look like a known function or some combination of known functions. For example in this way you can get a polynomial approximation of some degree of your interest w.r.t. MMSE criterion. Any better approximations are usually possible.

Comment: @Seyhmus-Güngören Thanks so much; I agree that that choice diverges quickly and it is the reason for which I have not accepted it to imply. But, I suppose that for some functions the divergence would occur very late. For example, $\ln(x)$ is very similar to $ψ(x)$ and it may keep the precision in a large domain. but for such suggestion there is another problem about how to solve the system after substitution Also I hope an analytic closed form by solving the system of integral equations or the system of series equations by substituting the $ψ(.)$ by its integral or series representation.