# Solving an integral (or series) equations system

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functional-equations, integral-equations, polygamma

Peace be upon you,

In the question [A late-diverging "approximating solution" for a system of functional equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893811/solving-an-integral-or-series-equations-system-which-is-the-analytic-solution), I have asked for an approximating solution for a system of functional equations.

**Here, I have presented some alternative forms of that system, to be analytically solved**.

Since the real part of the domains of its psi functions are positive we can write[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations) it as
\begin{align*}
\psi(s)=-\gamma + \int_0^1\frac{1-x^{s+1}}{1-x}
\end{align*}
where $γ$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. So, we can rewrite our system to become
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\int_0^1\frac{x^{\alpha+\beta+1}-x^{\alpha+1}}{1-x}=c_1\\
\int_0^1\frac{x^{\alpha+\beta+1}-x^{\beta+1}}{1-x}=c_2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Also, using the Newton series we can write[[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Newton_series)
\begin{align*}
\psi(s)=-\gamma-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\binom{s+1}{k}}
\end{align*}
So, we can rewrite our system to become
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\binom{\alpha+\beta+1}{k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\binom{\alpha+1}{k}}=c_1\\
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\binom{\alpha+\beta+1}{k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\binom{\beta+1}{k}}=c_2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Also, using the Recurrence formula and characterization we can write[[3]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Recurrence_formula_and_characterization)
\begin{align*}
\psi(s)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{s+k+1}\right)
\end{align*}
So, we can rewrite our system to become
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta+k+1}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{\alpha+k+1}\right)=c_1\\
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta+k+1}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{\beta+k+1}\right)=c_2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Is there any hint for "analytically solving" one of the aforementioned systems using?